# API fetching data in wrong order in swift

Tags: swift, api

I have 2 API.Data from 1st API is sent as input to 2nd API.
The data from 1st API is as follows:

```
{
                "id": 18,
                "mname": "Greg",
                "cname": "Pinto",
                "business_type": "Nanny",
                "mcontact": "437-965-7895",
                "memail": "kiddiecaretest@gmail.com",
                "mzipcode": "BB15026",
                "maddress": "Enford Crescent1",
                "city": "Saint George",
                "province": "Saint George",
                "mdesc": null,
                "image": "nanny_18_logo_3.png",
                "mpassword": "123456789",
                "mstatus": 1,
                "memstatus": 1,
                "created_at": "2020-08-19 10:30:41",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-21 15:17:51",
                "company_id": "PIN187864",
                "sq1": 1,
                "sq2": 2,
                "sq3": 4,
                "sq1a": "Kaur",
                "sq2a": "Ans1",
                "sq3a": "Ans2",
                "skills": "Homework assistance, special assistance care",
                "billing_address": "",
                "exp_years": 2,
                "languages": "English",
                "step2": 1,
                "recent_booking": "1597847441"
            }
```

The id from this 1st API is appended into another array.
This array is looped and sent to second API as follows:

```
for i in 0..<(self.listData?.bookingData.nanniesList.count)!
                    {
                        self.getnannyrating(id:(self.listData?.bookingData.nanniesList[i].id)!)
                       
                    }

  func getnannyrating(id:Int)
        {
            let parameter:Parameters = ["request_type":"get_nanny_rating","nanny_id":id]
    
            
            print("getnannyrating id is",parameter)
            
            AF.request(mainURL+URLS.coupon.rawValue, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                
                do {
                    
                    let user = try decoder.decode(RatingModel.self, from: response.data!)
                    self.ratingData = user
                    print("rating data is",self.ratingData)
                    
                   // self.rating.append((self.ratingData?.rating)!)
                 
                    
                    if let rating = self.ratingData?.rating
                    {
                        self.rating.append(rating)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        self.rating.append(0.0)
                    }
                    
                    print("ratings are ",self.rating,self.rating.count)
                    if self.rating.count == (self.listData?.bookingData.nanniesList.count)!
                    {
                        self.nomatchingview.isHidden = true
                        self.tableview7.isHidden = false
                        self.tableview7.delegate = self
                        self.tableview7.dataSource = self
                        self.tableview7.reloadData()
                    }
                    }
       
                catch {
                    print("error is",error)
                }
    }
    }
```

The parameters for 2nd API is taking properly from 1st API(The id),but inside the 2nd API call,the data order is getting changed.Please let me know what is the issue with this looping of API.

Answer (score 0):

The order doesn't preserve in your loop is due to the fact that **every API calls in the loop, i.e., `getnannyrating(id:)`s are called asynchronously.** Which mean the tasks start at approximately the same time, but each takes different time to finish loading.

For example, task 1 and task 2 start at the same time, but task 1 takes 3 seconds to load while task 2 takes 2 seconds, and then result array would be like `[task_2_res, task_1_res]`.

Do solve this, you can try using the `DispatchSemaphore` ([doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore) here), which will execute task only if the previous task is finished. I.e., task 2 would begin at the moment where task 1 finishes.

Example:

In `getnannyrating(id:)`, we will need another parameter:

```swift
func getnannyrating(id: Int, semaphore: DispatchSemaphore) {
    ...
    // Turn the semaphore signal on in the AF completion handler:
    AF.request(mainURL+URLS.coupon.rawValue, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
        semaphore.signal()
    ...
}
```

Then in the loop, do the following so iterations will end only if semaphore gets a signal change from `getnannyrating(id:semaphore:)`:

```swift
for i in 0..<(self.listData?.bookingData.nanniesList.count)! {
    // Create a semaphore with initial value of 1
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

    // Pass the semaphore to this method
    self.getnannyrating(id: (self.listData?.bookingData.nanniesList[i].id)!, semaphore: semaphore)
    
    // Ask the semaphore to wait until the signal changes in getnannryrating
    semaphore.wait()
}
```

Comment: I have the data from the 1st api and looped and then sent to 2nd API.So if have array of id,then where exactly would i start the 2nd API call and how to do this sort of result array?

Comment: i will check and let u know

Comment: I tried the code as given above.In the 1st call of the for loop itself.it is paused and has not gone further.That is inside the func getnannyid() and after the API call.

Comment: I just tested a similar setup and it worked. Did you make sure you included `semaphore.signal()` in your AF completion?

Comment: @saranya Try changing `let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)` to `let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)`

Comment: @saranya Sorry I missed your message, lets continue the discussion [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223184/discussion-between-eric-hua-and-saranya)